# A specific SO post is hurting privacy on the internet

Tags: discussion, support

I found a kind of rusty nail that is hurting the privacy of users on the internet. There is a particular post, that if followed, results in compromise of user credentials, and account access.  In my profession I have encountered applications that are following [broken security recommendations listed on a specific StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336678/login-without-https-how-to-secure/25758425#25758425).  This post is deeply misleading, and it is causing harm.

For the safety of the internet,  I would like the accepted answer deleted,  and the question locked so that no changes can be made.

I love SO, and I'm powerless over this problem. Please help defend privacy on the net.

Comment: Have you downvoted and left a comment on the offending post?

Comment: @Undo He did leave [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336678/login-without-https-how-to-secure/25758425#comment43903941_25758425) some time ago.

Comment: @Undo,  yes and the post has been flagged.

Comment: Vandalising the post is not the solution.

Comment: @ChrisF sitting back and watching users get hurt is NOT an option.  Vulnerable code hurts real people.

Comment: @Rook "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"

Comment: @Mooseman What if this where a medical stack excange, and the accepted post killed people?  Would that be enough?

Comment: @Rook Health SE will have its own set of challenges. That's unrelated to the question at hand. The fact that a little knowledge can be dangerous is very true. But I don't think we should assume that every user is a brainless monkey that automatically takes the accepted answer as fact.

Comment: Also, Health can (and likely will) set up rules to get rid of dangerous answers. That's something that  should be solved at the site level, not at the network lever.

Comment: Considering we're living in a post-heartbleed world, going apeshite over this question seems a bit pointless.  The fact that your answer, if followed, would have still left many people vulnerable to attack *for years* is some sweet irony, come to think of it.

Comment: @Won't at least heartbleed, poodle, and every flaw in TLS can be patched.  The only way to fix cargo cult security is by removing it.

Answer (score 10):

The answer has been downvoted by several users -- this is the correct response to inaccurate or poor answers.

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336738/1234256) has been upvoted by **47 users** and awarded a bounty. This is obviously preferred by the community.

You shouldn't believe everything you read on the internet...

Comment: The whole point of the SE model _is_ to have question/answer pairs, though. I suspect those unfamiliar with SE (likely many of the 13k users who have seen that post) don't realize the implications of an accepted answer vs downvotes. Especially since they can't see downvotes... though in this case all I can do is facepalm..

Comment: @Mooseman I agree,  but this noise is spreading.

Comment: @enderland From the tour page on every site: "Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked."

Comment: @Mooseman I'm sure most people reading posts from google take the time to read the help center..

Comment: @enderland That may be the case, but we can't cover the internet in bubble wrap either.